# Add data into new added row in `DataGridView` from `DataBindingSource`

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In `Form4` i have a `DataGridView` named `DbTableDataGridView`.
In `Form3` there is a set of fields (text boxes) that are all bound to the `DbTableBindingSource` . When I run application the `Form4` shows up. There is a button to open new form (`Form3`) and in there enter details about customers to be added as new row into database (`DataGridView`). My code for the "Add" button in `Form4` looks like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Me.DbTableDataGridView.Refresh()
        Me.DbTableBindingSource.AddNew()

        Form3.ShowDialog()

        Form3.ImiéTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.NazwiskoTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.Numer_TelefonuTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.Numer_RejestracyjnyTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.MarkaTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.ModelTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.Poj_SilnikaTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.RocznikTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.PaliwoTextBox.Text = ""
        Form3.Data_PrzyjeciaDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now
        Form3.RichTextBox1.Text = ""

    End Sub
```

It does add new row, selects it and clears entries in the text boxes (that are bound into 'DbTableBindingSource'.
In this form after I fill in all the fields I press button save:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try



            Me.Validate()

            Form4.DbTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.DbTableTableAdapter.Update(CartronicDBDataSet.dbTable)
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(CartronicDBDataSet)
            DbTableTableAdapter.Fill(Form4.CartronicDBDataSet.dbTable)

            MsgBox("Saved")


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Blad zapisu. Sprobuj ponownie. W razie potrzeby zamknij, a nastepnie uruchom ponownie program Cartronic")
        End Try


    End Sub
```

It goes to the message "Saved" but actually does not fill in added new recently.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done what you have suggested but little bit simpler.
Assigned all text boxes to each cell in current row as follows:

```
Form4.DbTableDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value = Me.NazwiskoTextBox.Text.ToString
        Form4.DbTableDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = Me.ImiéTextBox.Text.ToString
```

It works fine.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is no link that I can see between Form3 and your data.

I'd recommend passing the newly created data row to a new instance of Form3.

1. Get the reference to your newly added row
2. Create a new Form3 (avoid default instance forms, they're ugly and evil). This will mean you don't need to clear the textboxes as you have a brand new form every time.
3. Pass the datarow into your form where you will bind it directly to the textboxes

   ```
   Dim newRow = CType(Me.DbTableBindingSource.AddNew(), DataRow)
   Using frmEditor As New Form3
       frmEditor.DataSource = newRow
       frmEditor.ShowDialog()
   End Using
   ```

In form3 add the property (or preferably a constructor)

```
Private mDataSource As DataRow
Public Property DataSource As DataRow
    Get
        Return mDataSource
    End Get
    Set(value As DataRow)
        mDataSource = value
        Me.ImiéTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", mDataSource, "ImiéFieldName")
        ' ....
    End Set
End Property
```

If you use this approach then you can get rid of all of the textbox clearing code.

Comment: In Form3.Desiner.vb i changed all the text box instances that were bound with my binding source. Initially it was  Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.DbTableBindingSource, "Dodano Przez", True)) . And I change them all to  Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Form4.DbTableBindingSource, "Dodano Przez", True)) instead (from "Me" to "Form4"). It does run ok but i get an errors saying that: 'WindowsApplication4.My.MyProject' has no property named 'Forms'.

Comment: I did bind each relevant text box in Form3 using text properties->Data->DataBindings->Text and selected my binding source. But this seems not to work. It only worked when I changed in the code to bind in the Form4 but have this errors and all bindings in properties disappears.

Comment: A few issues here. 1 never modify anything in a .designer file. It'll get overwritten.  I dont use binding sources myself so I'm not aware of their usage. So I'd say either use the binding source or use my approach. 3 never refer to something in one form from another (eg refer to form4.dbtablebinding from form 3). 4 never use a default form instance instead use new Form3 etc.

Comment: The problem you're getting relates to the me vs Form4 change you made. So I'd suggest stripping your bindings out of the designer and implementing the data source  property I showed. This binds to the correct object instance.  If you're going to use the existing binding source then you're still going to need to assign it a data source. Just boarding an aircraft now so I won't be available till tomorrow. Good luck